# Spring JmsListener not picking up messages

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Spring Boot 2.1.4 application which uses the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` to consume messages from IBM MQ 9.0 over SSL. I have noticed that in some unknown circumstances the listener’s connection to MQ still exists and is reported as connected within the logging and MQ Explorer, however the listener does not consume messages and they remain on the queue until the Spring Boot app is restarted. Logs do not report anything in the app or Queue Manager.

Ideally, I would like the `JmsListener` to recognize the fail state and re-connect on its own. I have read that configuring Heartbeat or Keep Alive on MQ and the client would help. The MQ channel is set to a 5 sec heartbeat interval, but not sure how to configure this or the keep-alive in our Spring Boot app.

Note: my `JmsListener` does reconnect on its own in the event of a caught exception with the MQ connection.

Jms Factory code:

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory));
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setErrorHandler(new DefaultJmsErrorHandler());
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
    configurer.configure(defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory, connectionFactory);
    return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
}
```

Listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${sys.to.app.core.queue}", containerFactory = "myFactory")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void onMessageReceived(final Message message) throws InboundQueueMessageException {...}
```

Comment: Would you share any piece of code you think could help us?

Comment: Unless you use a CCDT on the spring side, the HBINT will negotiate to the value of the SVRCONN.  But based on your description it does not sound like you are disconnected.   Which version of IBM MQ jar files are you using?  What is the full version of the queue manager?

Comment: May be `ibm.mq.pool.timeBetweenExpirationCheck` . See https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

Comment: There where some dead locks in some older maintenance levels.

Comment: @JoshMc IBM MQ jar 9.0.4, Spring JMS jar: 5.1.6, IBM MQ jar: 9.0.2, IBM MQ Manager: 9.1.0.5

Comment: @JoshMc so without the CCDT config in spring, HBINT has no effect?

Comment: Without a CCDT it will negotiate to the HBINT value of the SVRCONN.  With a CCDT it will negotiate to the higher of the value of the SVRCONN and the CLNTCONN.

Comment: Is it 9.0.4 or 9.0.2? Have you tried with a recent version,  9.1.0 7 for example?

Comment: @JoshMc, I'll try a newer version. Will report back the results.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it should be the underlying plumbing that takes care of the connection failure and reconnect, but if you have to do this then this might help.

Say you have a listener setup something like:

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name1}",
            containerFactory = "myListenerFactory",
            id = "Q1Object")
    public void receiveOO(MyMessageData data) {
       ...
    }
```

Then you could register an error handler for the listener factory. Inside which you could check if the listener is running, and if it isn't, restart it.

```java
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.*;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;


@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class MQConfigurationAndHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    // The listener registry allows us to control the @JmsListener endpoints
    private final JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    public MQConfigurationAndHandler(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                     JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.registry = registry;
    }


    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable e) {
        logger.warn("Listener error has been thrown");
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());

//        logger.info("Registered listeners IDs are : ");
//        for (String listenerId : registry.getListenerContainerIds()) {
//            logger.info("ID " + listenerId);
//        }

        logger.info("Checking listener");
        MessageListenerContainer mlc = registry.getListenerContainer("Q1Object");
        if (! mlc.isRunning()) {
            logger.warn("Listener has stopped running attempting restart");
            mlc.start();
        } else {
            logger.warn("Listener is running, something else is throwing an error");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Bean("myListenerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myCustomisedListenerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(this);

        return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: my JMS listener is re-connecting successfully for any caught exception (using the framework-providing feature). Unfortunately, I am dealing with a "silent exception" which goes undetected by JMS.

Comment: That will be the underlying exception listener